# How to use a file as a zpool?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, zfs

If I do

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tank/test/zpool bs=1M count=100
```

how can I treat the file `/tank/test/zpool` as a vdev, so I can use it as a zpool?

It is for zfs testing purposes only.

Comment: maybe you are missing a needed information, you are using solaris or linux?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is no need to create a loop device, you can simply use the file itself as a vdev:

```
zpool create test /tank/test/zpool
```

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: sudo truncate -s 64M /tank/test/zpool

Comment: @MaxRobbertze That's indeed a way to create a file but the OP already created a 100M file with the alternate `dd` method. Moreover, `truncate` was probably unavailable on her 2014 Solaris version.

Answer (score 5):

Create a loop device backed by the file.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/foo bs=1M count=128
losetup /dev/loop0 /tmp/foo
zpool create tank /dev/loop0
```

(The minimum disk size of 128 MB.)

Oops, didn't notice the Solaris tag. My instructions were for Linux. Instead of `losetup` you can use `lofiadm` under Solaris.

Comment: The two last steps should be exchangeable as long as you don't instruct `losetup` to mount starting at a given offset. I.e. as long as you use the full file as the block device.

Comment: Can this be used to bypass the  "Cannot resolve path" error I get if the file is on a network filesystem instead of local?